# send email with Laravel + Vuejs ajax

Tags: ajax, laravel, vuejs2

I have few forms on the page:
1) ask question about the product
2) ask for recall
etc.

At the moment I was able to setup one form to send email, but it doesn't work as I need.
I want to receive different emails depends on which form user sent to me.

Issues I need to solve:

1) in MainController I have hardcoded link to **new AskQuestion()**. So I am limited to send email only with the one template located in **mail.askquestion**. But I want to send email depends on which form user sent to me.

2) After mail is sent browser redirect to blank page - so I just see white screen. Even Redirect::back() is not working. Ideally I want to stay on the page, where form was submitted without redirect. Just with flash message success or failed. I cannot find good instrucion how to do this using ajax.

**routes\web.php**

```
Route::post('/askproduct','MainController@askproduct');
```

**App\Http\Controllers\MainController.php**

```
    public function askproduct(Request $request) {

        request()->validate(['customer_email' => 'required|email']);
        Mail::to( env('MAIL_TO_ADDRESS') )->send(new Email());
        return Redirect::back()->withMessage('Ваш вопрос отправлен! В ближайшее время мы свяжемся с вами.')->withClass('success');

    }
```

**App\Mail\Email.php**

```
    public function build(Request $request)
    {
        $this->view('mail.askproduct')
                    ->subject('Новый вопрос по товару')
                    ->withRequest($request);
    }
```

**resources\js\components\AskQuestionModal.vue**

```
<template>

    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Ask Question</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" @click="$emit('close')">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
        <form method="POST">
          <input type="hidden" name="_token" :value="csrf">
          <div class="modal-body">
              <p>{{ product }}</p>
              <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="product" :value="product">
              <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="currentUrl" :value="currentUrl">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="customer_name" placeholder="Ваше имя" :class="{ 'form-control--error': $v.customer_name.$error }" v-model.trim="$v.customer_name.$model">
              <div class="error" v-if="!$v.customer_name.required">Введите имя</div>
              <div class="error" v-if="!$v.customer_name.minLength">Имя должно содержать минимум {{$v.customer_name.$params.minLength.min}} буквы.</div>
              <div class="error" v-if="!$v.customer_name.cyrillic">Имя должно состоять только из русских букв</div>

              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="customer_email" placeholder="Ваш e-mail" :class="{ 'form-control--error': $v.customer_email.$error }" v-model.trim="$v.customer_email.$model">
              <div class="error" v-if="!$v.customer_email.required">Введите email</div>
              <div class="error" v-if="!$v.customer_email.email">Введите существующий email</div>

              <input type="tel" class="form-control" name="customer_phone" placeholder="Ваш телефон +7 (123) 456-78-99" :class="{ 'form-control--error': $v.customer_phone.$error }" v-model.trim="$v.customer_phone.$model" v-mask="'+# (###) ###-##-##'">
              <div class="error" v-if="!$v.customer_phone.required">Введите номер телефона</div>

              <textarea type="text" rows="3" class="form-control" name="customer_question" placeholder="Ваш вопрос"></textarea>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="button button_fill" type="submit"><span>Отправить вопрос</span></button>
          </div>
        </form>
    </div>


</template>

<script>
    import { alpha, email, helpers, maxLength, minLength, numeric, required } from 'vuelidate/lib/validators';
    import {mask} from 'vue-the-mask';

    export const cyrillic = helpers.regex('cyrillic', /^[А-Яа-яёЁ\s]+$/);


    export default {
        name: "AskQuestionModal",

        data: function () {
          return {
            currentUrl: window.location.pathname,
            csrf: document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content'),
            customer_name: '',
            customer_email: '',
            customer_phone: ''
          }
        },
        directives: {mask},
        props: ['product'],

        mounted() {
           console.log('AskQuestionModal component mounted.')
        },

        validations: {
          customer_name: {
            required,
            cyrillic,
            minLength: minLength(3)
          },
          customer_email: {
            required,
            email
          },
          customer_phone: {
            required
          }

        }

    }
</script>
```

**resources\views\mail\askquestion.blade.php

```
<p>Клиент отправил вопрос по товару {{ $request['product'] }}</p>
<p>Заявка отправлена со страницы: {{ env('APP_URL').$request['currentUrl'] }}</p>
<p>Имя: {{ $request['customer_name'] }}</p>
<p>Почта: {{ $request['customer_email'] }}</p>
<p>Тел: {{ $request['customer_phone'] }}</p>
<p>Вопрос: {{ $request['customer_question'] }}</p>
```

Comment: Is the end point for both forms the same? If so, is there a reason you haven't separated them?

Comment: What do you mean under end point? They are located on same page, but in different vue components. So forms should be absolutely independent. Here I posted only one vue component for example, because another is very similar

Comment: An endpoint is a url essentially. So, my question is are you submitting the forms to the same url or are they different?

Comment: URL is the same. Actually I want to have callback form on every page and askproduct form on all product pages. So on some pages they will be together

Comment: Ok. So is there a reason you're having them go to the same url if there are serving different purposes e.g. why not `/askproduct` and `/recall` (or something along those lines). This would be an easy way to send the different emails and you're not having to conditionally check what needs to happen in the controller.

Comment: I don't have `/askproduct` and `/recall` pages. And I don't really want to create new pages for POST requests. I think that it is better to stay on current page with status message to user sent with success or failed.

Comment: They wouldn't be pages. They would `POST` endpoints i.e. a route and a controller method. This is the way things like this would usually be set up rather than having one end point for multiple different things.

Comment: Ok. I create 2 routes and 2 functions in Controller. But this is not the main deal

Comment: Don't return redirects from `Mailable`s, instead just call the mailable and then return the redirect from the controller. The reason you're only seeing a white screen is because nothing is being returned from your controller.

Comment: Where are you setting the `$request` variable inside `AskQuestion::build()` method? Looks like you forgot to pass it as an argument in the constructor.

Comment: Thanks gyus. I changed my code according to advices and now it works much better. New code already changed directly in question above.

Comment: I don't set `$request` variable inside `AskQuestion __constructor`. I just declare `use Illuminate\Http\Request` in the class header and then `$request` is available 
 to be passed in `AskQuestion::build()` method like in any other class. No need to touch constructor.

Comment: Is it possible to pass view and subject as parameter to new Email instance?
Because I don't think I really need to have 2 Mailable classes to do the same thing. 

Should I do also check if we have errors during mailsend and generate error message if yes?


Probably I will loose connection to mailgun or DNS server or other problems. But I have no idea how to check that.

Comment: like that `Mail::to( env('MAIL_TO_ADDRESS') )->send(new Email(['view' = 'mail.askproduct', 'subject' = 'Новый вопрос по товару')));`